# Getting data update for progress indicator when getting JSON response from server? Swift NSURLSession

Tags: swift, nsurlsession

**Premise**:
I have written a networking layer that is based on NSURLSession. Backend is providing JSON response. (For sake of simplicity lets say we need to do this in NSURLSession
I have been asked to show the progress indicator that is based on the data that depends on how much data is downloaded.

In my first impression, is that even possible. It's not a zip or image file. Its JSON response. 
If I am wrong then do we already have that is hidden in NSURLSession.

Since I am using callback completion handler how that would be possible. Because the completion handler is going to run when the request is complete.

**My first question** if that is even possible(please not we are talking about JSON response). if the answer is yes. Then I would love to help you view how it can be achieved.

I have no code as I have written no code. I am planning to use NSURLSession as my choice of weapon.

Comment: You can use the delegate of `URLSession`. The fact that's it's an image, a zip file or a JSON doesn't matter. What you download is a `Data` object, which might be quick or not depending on its size, connectivity, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly possible. Here is an example of how:

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,URLSessionDelegate,URLSessionDataDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var progress: UIProgressView!

    var buffer:NSMutableData = NSMutableData()
    var session:URLSession?
    var dataTask:URLSessionDataTask?
    let url = URL(string:"https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8zkg.png" )!
    var expectedContentLength = 0


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        progress.progress = 0.0
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let mainqueue = OperationQueue.main
        session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: mainqueue)
        dataTask = session?.dataTask(with: URLRequest(url: url))
        dataTask?.resume()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive response: URLResponse, completionHandler: (URLSession.ResponseDisposition) -> Void) {

        //here you can get full lenth of your content
        expectedContentLength = Int(response.expectedContentLength)
        print(expectedContentLength)
        completionHandler(.allow)
    }
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data) {

        buffer.append(data)

        let percentageDownloaded = Float(buffer.length) / Float(expectedContentLength)
        progress.progress =  percentageDownloaded
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
        //use buffer here.Download is done
        progress.progress = 1.0   // download 100% complete
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. My question is specific about JSON data

Comment: There is no need to update the progressView manually. `progress.observedProgress = dataTask.progress`

Comment: @LeoDabus That is really handly. Was it always an option? I would use dataTask.progress in all my future cases.

Comment: @Frankenstein I think It has been available since iOS 11

Comment: I tried that out on playground but, it doesn't seem to update every time the value change.

Comment: import Foundation
let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: "http://i.stack.imgur.com/b8zkg.png")!)
dataTask.resume()
print(dataTask.progress.fractionCompleted)